# renewcommand - add characters

Tags: bibtex, citing

I replaced the \citet command by

```
\renewcommand{\citep}{[\citenum}
```

The "[" als introduces a square bracket before the citiation number, however, I couldn't figure out how to also add a closing one.

Unfortunately, my internet search was not successful.

Comment: Without testing (you did not provide something to test) i would guess `\renewcommand{\citep}{{[\citenum]}}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197095/latex-bold-not-bold-enough-in-math#comment456701_197095

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work! I will provide a MWE later (sorry, forgot again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you want to do this. With a simple `\cite` and the `plain`
style you'll get the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\renewcommand\citep[1]{[\citenum{#1}\relax]}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
        author    = {John Lennon},
        booktitle = {A book with articles},
        editor    = {Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey},
        title     = {This is my article in this book},
        year      = {1965},
        location  = {Liverpool},
        pages     = {65--87},
        publisher = {Cavern Club},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
foo\citep{lennon1965} bar\cite{lennon1965}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

However, using `biblatex` instead of `natbib` makes more sense.

[image]

Comment: That did the job, thanks a lot!